# Probability distribution for malfunctions

Tags: probability

I am trying to model the time it takes until a malfunction appears. For example the time a light-bulb will last. I would like the probability that the light-bulb will burn out at a certain moment (given it hadn't bunt yet) to increase as a function of the time ($P(x | X \geq x$) should be monotonic increasing). That is, an old light-bulb is more likely to burn out at the moment than a new one. (Obviously, I can't use a memory-less probability distribution). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a distribution with a maximum lifetime (say $c$) then you might consider $$F(x)=1-\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)^\beta$$ $$f(x)= \frac{\beta}{c}\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)^{\beta-1}$$ for some positive $\beta$: for $\beta=1$ this gives a uniform distribution on $[0,c]$.  It is a kind of scaled Beta distribution with $\alpha=1$.  Its expectation is $\frac{c}{1+\beta}$.

Its hazard function or failure rate, which you want to be monotonically increasing, is $$\lambda(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}=\frac{\beta}{c}\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)^{-1}.$$

While not memoryless, it does have shape-memorylessness: conditioned on not having failed yet, the remaining distribution has the same shape as the original distribution but has been scaled; scale-free statistics such as the coefficient of variation, skewness or kurtosis do not change.

Answer (score 0):

The Weibull distribution seems to satisfy my request.